# Optimizing query to retrieve data from different databases spread over different servers to send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application that uses an `Admin` database which contains details of all clients and their databases (along with the name of servers) they all use to connect this application. All the client databases contain a table named `NotifyQueue`. This table holds all the queued mails to be sent at preset times (preset means time interval set by each client).

Our front end application has a service written that triggers the sending of mails from all of this `NotifyQueue` tables for all the clients. Problem is we have currently over 600 databases  spread over different servers and we need to extract those 1000s of `NotifyQueue` mails and send them. This takes a considerably lot of time sometimes around 15 - 20 mins. What we need is to keep sending this lot of mails every 1 minute. Currently the logic used is to loop through each database and retrieve the queued mails then again loop through each mail to send it. The code is below

```
private void SendEMail(List<EmailNotifyQueue> listNotifyQueue, SqlConnection objConn, string Module, EmailSettings emailSettings)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listNotifyQueue.Count; i++)
                {
                    ClientConfig cfg = ClientConfig.CurrentSetings;
                    objemailinfo = new EmailInformation();
                    objemailinfo.DatabaseName = emailSettings.DatabaseName;
                    objemailinfo.DatabaseServer = emailSettings.DatabaseServer;
                    objemailinfo.SmtpServer = cfg.SMTPServer;
                    objemailinfo.RequireAuthentication = emailSettings.EmailRequiresAuthentication;
                    objemailinfo.SmtpUserName = emailSettings.EmailUserName;
                    objemailinfo.SmtpPassWord = emailSettings.EmailPassword;
                    objemailinfo.EnableNotifications = emailSettings.EnableNotifications;
                    if (lstNotifyQueue[i].ToAddress != string.Empty)
                    {
                        objemailinfo.To = ExcludeMail(lstNotifyQueue[i].ToAddress.Replace(';', ','), emailSettings.EmailExclusions, emailSettings.DatabaseName);
                        objemailinfo.Body = lstNotifyQueue[i].Body;
                        if (Module == "IM")
                            objemailinfo.From = lstNotifyQueue[i].FromAddress;
                        else
                            objemailinfo.From = emailSettings.EmailAddress;
                        if (objemailinfo.From != string.Empty)
                        {
                            objemailinfo.Subject = lstNotifyQueue[i].Subject;
                            if (objemailinfo.To != string.Empty)
                                if (objemailinfo.sendEmail())
                                {
                                    ChangeEmailNotifyQueue(Convert.ToInt32(lstNotifyQueue[i].Key), objConn, emailSettings.DatabaseName, Module);
                                    if (!String.Equals(Module, "IM"))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            LogEmailNotificationInModules(lstNotifyQueue[i], objConn);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            //Let the exception not break the email sending logic so simply log the exception
                                            SchedulerHelper.LogEmailNotification(SchedulerHelper.FormatException(emailSettings.DatabaseName, "Scheduler", "SendEMail",
                                                "Exception occured while Logging EmailNotification Status" + ex.Message));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SchedulerHelper.LogEmailNotification(SchedulerHelper.FormatException(emailSettings.DatabaseName, "Scheduler", "SendEMail", ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

This method is called for each database which means, currently this will be called 600 times

Could any one help me find a better solution to quickly retrieve all the data and send it inside 1 min?

**Update**
We are planning on using thread to run simultaneously but the logic is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you need this to be under 1 minute because you want this to execute this every minute, so that there is only a short delay before sending out an email.

Ideally you need to do this the other way around. Put the NotifyQueue table in a central place and then have the 600 different clients write records into that table. (or have the DB's insert data to central location in a trigger) You can then run the service over the single table and process all the records with one very quick call and loop. This should get you well under 1 minute.

Otherwise add configuration to your service to allow you to specify a set of databases and then run multiple copies of it, each dealing with only a small sub-set of databases so that the time each spend by each is less than 1 minute.

Comment: Yes your first method could work but it is not advisable to change the query since there could be local databases too. I am changing my question